# Equivalent of ToString() on an enum type in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

In C# you can declare an enum and once you have set its value call ToString on the variable and get a string representation of the value of the enum.

How do you do this in C++/CLI using a managed enum?

Answer (score 7):

Whilst the other answers are not incorrect, I found myself with the same problem. In my case, I had declared a standard C++ enum and forgot to use the CLI syntax (even though I had it been exposed in public properties without compiler warnings!).

The proper syntax for a C++/CLI enum is (Note the word 'class'):

```
public enum class SomeEnum {
    Value1,
    Value2
}
```

NB: You can also use 'struct' rather than 'class'.

You will also need to go back through your code and change any assignments (the compiler will happily show you the errors however) from this:

```
SomeEnum value = Value1;
```

to this:

```
SomeEnum value = SomeEnum::Value1;
```

You will now find that 'ToString()' works as you'd expect it to.

Answer (score 5):

Isn't it the same syntax ?

```
MyEnum enumValue = MyEnum::Enum1;
Console::WriteLine(enumValue.ToString());
```

Look at this page of the book "Pro Visual C++/CLI and the .NET 3.5 Platform" in [Google Books](http://books.google.fr/books?id=MTJIdMoaY1gC&lpg=PA43&ots=TVxzvSAlnq&dq=c%2B%2B%20cli%20enum%20tostring&hl=en&pg=PA43#v=onepage&q=c++%20cli%20enum%20tostring&f=false)

> "The ToString() method for enum prints out the enum name as a character string"

Comment: I get "left of .ToString() must have class/struct/union"

Comment: @CJBrew I get that error too unless I make the enum public.

Answer (score 1):

ToString() should return the name of the enum value. Furthermore, if you decorate the managed Enum with a [Flags] attribute, then eg `Colour::Red | Colour::Blue` will ToString() as "Red, Blue". (This is from memory from Marcus Heege's book "Expert Visual C++/CLI: .NET for Visual C++ Programmers", not tried it myself)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was likely resolved.
I thought someone else might find it useful:
**NOT:** The number of members can be up to 96. ( [ENUM96.inl](https://github.com/GERD0GDU/ENUM96/blob/main/Enum96Test/ENUM96.inl) )

```cpp
#include "ENUM96.inl"

//
// DirectShowDeviceType
// ENUM96 sample definition
//
ENUM96(DirectShowDeviceType, unsigned int,
    None = 0,
    Input = 1,    // Capture
    Output = 2,   // Renderer
    Video = 4,    // Video support
    Audio = 8     // Audio support
    );

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    DirectShowDeviceType eDevType = DirectShowDeviceType::Input
        | DirectShowDeviceType::Video
        | DirectShowDeviceType::Audio;

    printf("[ENUM96 Test]\n\n");

    _tprintf(_T("> %-24s --> \"%s\" (%u)\n"), _T("ToString()")
        , eDevType.ToString()
        , eDevType.ToUInt32());

    printf("> %-24s --> %s\n", "HasFlag(Output)",
        eDevType.HasFlag(DirectShowDeviceType::Output)
        ? "true"
        : "false");

    printf("> %-24s --> %s\n", "HasFlag(Input)",
        eDevType.HasFlag(DirectShowDeviceType::Input)
        ? "true"
        : "false");

    printf("> %-24s --> %s\n", "HasFlag(Video)",
        eDevType.HasFlag(DirectShowDeviceType::Video)
        ? "true"
        : "false");

    printf("> %-24s --> %s\n", "HasFlag(Audio)",
        eDevType.HasFlag(DirectShowDeviceType::Audio)
        ? "true"
        : "false");

    printf("> %-24s --> %s\n", "HasFlag(Input | Audio)",
        eDevType.HasFlag(DirectShowDeviceType::Input | DirectShowDeviceType::Audio)
        ? "true"
        : "false");

    printf("> %-24s --> %s\n", "HasFlag(Input | Video)",
        eDevType.HasFlag(DirectShowDeviceType::Input | DirectShowDeviceType::Video)
        ? "true"
        : "false");

    printf("> %-24s --> %s\n", "HasFlag(Output | Video)",
        eDevType.HasFlag(DirectShowDeviceType::Output | DirectShowDeviceType::Video)
        ? "true"
        : "false");

    printf("> %-24s --> %s\n", "HasFlag(Video | Audio)",
        eDevType.HasFlag(DirectShowDeviceType::Video | DirectShowDeviceType::Audio)
        ? "true"
        : "false");

    printf("\n");
    printf("> // Remove 'Video' flag\n");
    eDevType &= ~DirectShowDeviceType::Video;

    _tprintf(_T("> %-24s --> \"%s\" (%u)\n"), _T("ToString()")
        , eDevType.ToString()
        , eDevType.ToUInt32());

    printf("> %-24s --> %s\n", "HasFlag(Video)",
        eDevType.HasFlag(DirectShowDeviceType::Video)
        ? "true"
        : "false");

    printf("> %-24s --> %s\n", "HasFlag(Video | Audio)",
        eDevType.HasFlag(DirectShowDeviceType::Video | DirectShowDeviceType::Audio)
        ? "true"
        : "false");

    printf("> %-24s --> %s\n", "HasFlag(Audio)",
        eDevType.HasFlag(DirectShowDeviceType::Audio)
        ? "true"
        : "false");

    printf("> %-24s --> %s\n", "HasFlag(Input)",
        eDevType.HasFlag(DirectShowDeviceType::Input)
        ? "true"
        : "false");

    printf("> %-24s --> %s\n", "HasFlag(Input | Audio)",
        eDevType.HasFlag(DirectShowDeviceType::Input | DirectShowDeviceType::Audio)
        ? "true"
        : "false");

    printf("\n");
    printf("> // List ENUM members\n");
    printf("> %-24s --> %u\n", "MemberCount",
        eDevType.GetMemberCount());
    for (int i = 0; i < eDevType.GetMemberCount(); i++) {
        DirectShowDeviceType eMember = eDevType.GetMember(i);
        _tprintf(_T("  [%u] %s\n"), eMember.ToUInt32(), eMember.ToString());
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

##### The result will be as shown below.

```
    [ENUM96 Test]
    
    > ToString()               --> "Input | Video | Audio" (13)
    > HasFlag(Output)          --> false
    > HasFlag(Input)           --> true
    > HasFlag(Video)           --> true
    > HasFlag(Audio)           --> true
    > HasFlag(Input | Audio)   --> true
    > HasFlag(Input | Video)   --> true
    > HasFlag(Output | Video)  --> false
    > HasFlag(Video | Audio)   --> true
    
    > // Remove 'Video' flag
    > ToString()               --> "Input | Audio" (9)
    > HasFlag(Video)           --> false
    > HasFlag(Video | Audio)   --> false
    > HasFlag(Audio)           --> true
    > HasFlag(Input)           --> true
    > HasFlag(Input | Audio)   --> true
    
    > // List ENUM members
    > MemberCount              --> 5
      [0] None
      [1] Input
      [2] Output
      [4] Video
      [8] Audio
```